# How to compiling pcre-8.45

Tags: pcre

I tried to compile the dynamic lib of pcre but an error occured:

> ./libtool: eval: line 10769: syntax error near unexpected token `('

here is the pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNrAV.png)

Comment: You seem to have a file or directory pathname with `(1)` in it. My guess that is a result of the way that you downloaded or unzipped the library source code.  Or something.  Either way, you need rename the offending file or directory to get rid of the `(1)` that is breaking the build script.  Then start again.

Comment: In future: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)